# CreateReactApp: embed end-user plugin at runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

We have a React application created/deployed using CreateReactApp.

This application is able to display some widgets. We've predefined types of widgets deployed with our own application. We'd like the end-users of our application to be able to develop their own type of widgets - using a dev tool like Webstorm/VisualStudio - and deploy them into our application.

1. Our application needs to provide a public API and a plugin dev library
2. We want the plugins to be able to use the libraries our application is using (e.g. React, material-ui…)
3. We need a way to "load" end-user code that is registering new widget types using our public API.

Can we do that using CreateReactApp or do we need to eject?

What are the best practices for doing this?

Comment: They can publish the widget to npm (or a private registry) and the app can consume it.

Comment: @Marc Polizzi maybe you could provide some usage scenario? What is the ideal workflow? Say, a user registers some widget. What happens after that, what impact does it have on the app?

Comment: @Marc Polizzi sharing a RFC by Backstage of how they are going to approach dynamic plugins as a way to extend their React frontend, may be interesting to you or someone interested in this question: https://github.com/backstage/backstage/issues/18372

Answer (score 0):

I have more a suggestion than an answer, a best practice for that can depend on the structure of your current project, so I don't think there's a right answer. I wrote a small proof-of-concept, feel free to fork and use that, if it helps: https://github.com/anderick/react-dynamic-components.

> 1. Our application needs to provide a public API and a plugin dev library

To solve this you can create a folder structure to let users upload their component projects.

You need a name or id to link this new uploaded project so you can load it later.

> 2. We want the plugins to be able to use the libraries our application is using (e.g. React, material-ui…)

If the use is only allowed to use the libraries you already have, you don't need to worry about their `package.json`.

In case you want to allow users to use their own libs, it adds some complexity on how to process this during runtime.

> 3. We need a way to "load" end-user code that is registering new widget types using our public API.

You can use create-react-app in this approach, but you may need a good definition of an entry point (in my example project, I'm using `Index.js` as the file I'll use as the main component of the project), or some kind of `descriptor`(maybe extending `package.json`) so you can read from your application to understand how to load the component. I'd go with the first approach, `convention over configuration` is more simple, and you can expand from that with a descriptor later.